# Extract image link from img tag in Telegram Instant View

Tags: telegram, telegram-instant-view

I've added `$body` variable in template like this:

```
$body: //div[has-class("story-content")]
```

The `$body` has the image inside. But the image isn't loading and showing something like this:

[image]

Maybe it's a default image if any image is unable to load from that site. I don't know. But the image is loading from browser without any issue.

The image tag looks something like this:

```
<img src="https://images.somesite.com/somesite%2F2020-09%2F6d16d29c-1352-405f-a739-45dfb5f0f16f%2FOpu.jpeg?auto=format%2Ccompress&amp;format=webp&amp;w=360&amp;dpr=4.0" data-src="https://images.somesite.com/somesite%2F2020-09%2F6d16d29c-1352-405f-a739-45dfb5f0f16f%2FOpu.jpeg?auto=format%2Ccompress" alt="Alt_text" class="class1 class2 class3 class4 class5" loading="lazy">
```

Maybe Telegram can't scrape the image as the link doesn't have supported image extensions at the end. I was wondering if I can get the part from `https://` to `.jpeg`, from that image url.

Like, `https://images.somesite.com/somesite%2F2020-09%2F6d16d29c-1352-405f-a739-45dfb5f0f16f%2FOpu.jpeg` as the image url.

How can I do that?